# SoftwareSerial.h not found on Sodaq Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have an arduino sodaq with a MIcrochip LoRabee attached, as well as a GPS module. I am trying to use SoftwareSerial to read the GPS data but it won't recognise it!

The sketch was previously working on a Chinese cloned Nano and I was able to read the data fine. I've changed the ports to 4 and 5 (I was using 3 and 4 on the Chinese Nano) but other than that the code is identical.

Any ideas?

```cpp
#include <TinyGPS++.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
/*
   This sample code demonstrates the normal use of a TinyGPS++ (TinyGPSPlus) object.
   It requires the use of SoftwareSerial, and assumes that you have a
   4800-baud serial GPS device hooked up on pins 4(rx) and 3(tx).
*/
static const int RXPin = 2, TXPin = 3;
static const uint32_t GPSBaud = 9600;

// The TinyGPS++ object
TinyGPSPlus gps;

// The serial connection to the GPS device
SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ss.begin(GPSBaud);

  Serial.println(F("FullExample.ino"));
  Serial.println(F("An extensive example of many interesting TinyGPS++ features"));
  Serial.print(F("Testing TinyGPS++ library v. ")); Serial.println(TinyGPSPlus::libraryVersion());
  Serial.println(F("by Mikal Hart"));
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("Sats HDOP Latitude   Longitude   Fix  Date       Time     Date Alt    Course Speed Card  Distance Course Card  Chars Sentences Checksum"));
  Serial.println(F("          (deg)      (deg)       Age                      Age  (m)    --- from GPS ----  ---- to London  ----  RX    RX        Fail"));
  Serial.println(F("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
}

void loop()
{
  static const double LONDON_LAT = 51.508131, LONDON_LON = -0.128002;

  printInt(gps.satellites.value(), gps.satellites.isValid(), 5);
  printInt(gps.hdop.value(), gps.hdop.isValid(), 5);
  printFloat(gps.location.lat(), gps.location.isValid(), 11, 6);
  printFloat(gps.location.lng(), gps.location.isValid(), 12, 6);
  printInt(gps.location.age(), gps.location.isValid(), 5);
  printDateTime(gps.date, gps.time);
  printFloat(gps.altitude.meters(), gps.altitude.isValid(), 7, 2);
  printFloat(gps.course.deg(), gps.course.isValid(), 7, 2);
  printFloat(gps.speed.kmph(), gps.speed.isValid(), 6, 2);
  printStr(gps.course.isValid() ? TinyGPSPlus::cardinal(gps.course.value()) : "*** ", 6);

  unsigned long distanceKmToLondon =
    (unsigned long)TinyGPSPlus::distanceBetween(
      gps.location.lat(),
      gps.location.lng(),
      LONDON_LAT, 
      LONDON_LON) / 1000;
  printInt(distanceKmToLondon, gps.location.isValid(), 9);

  double courseToLondon =
    TinyGPSPlus::courseTo(
      gps.location.lat(),
      gps.location.lng(),
      LONDON_LAT, 
      LONDON_LON);

  printFloat(courseToLondon, gps.location.isValid(), 7, 2);

  const char *cardinalToLondon = TinyGPSPlus::cardinal(courseToLondon);

  printStr(gps.location.isValid() ? cardinalToLondon : "*** ", 6);

  printInt(gps.charsProcessed(), true, 6);
  printInt(gps.sentencesWithFix(), true, 10);
  printInt(gps.failedChecksum(), true, 9);
  Serial.println();

  smartDelay(1000);

  if (millis() > 5000 && gps.charsProcessed() < 10)
    Serial.println(F("No GPS data received: check wiring"));
}

// This custom version of delay() ensures that the gps object
// is being "fed".
static void smartDelay(unsigned long ms)
{
  unsigned long start = millis();
  do 
  {
    while (ss.available())
      gps.encode(ss.read());
  } while (millis() - start < ms);
}

static void printFloat(float val, bool valid, int len, int prec)
{
  if (!valid)
  {
    while (len-- > 1)
      Serial.print('*');
    Serial.print(' ');
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print(val, prec);
    int vi = abs((int)val);
    int flen = prec + (val < 0.0 ? 2 : 1); // . and -
    flen += vi >= 1000 ? 4 : vi >= 100 ? 3 : vi >= 10 ? 2 : 1;
    for (int i=flen; i<len; ++i)
      Serial.print(' ');
  }
  smartDelay(0);
}

static void printInt(unsigned long val, bool valid, int len)
{
  char sz[32] = "*****************";
  if (valid)
    sprintf(sz, "%ld", val);
  sz[len] = 0;
  for (int i=strlen(sz); i<len; ++i)
    sz[i] = ' ';
  if (len > 0) 
    sz[len-1] = ' ';
  Serial.print(sz);
  smartDelay(0);
}

static void printDateTime(TinyGPSDate &d, TinyGPSTime &t)
{
  if (!d.isValid())
  {
    Serial.print(F("********** "));
  }
  else
  {
    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d/%02d/%02d ", d.month(), d.day(), d.year());
    Serial.print(sz);
  }

  if (!t.isValid())
  {
    Serial.print(F("******** "));
  }
  else
  {
    char sz[32];
    sprintf(sz, "%02d:%02d:%02d ", t.hour(), t.minute(), t.second());
    Serial.print(sz);
  }

  printInt(d.age(), d.isValid(), 5);
  smartDelay(0);
}

static void printStr(const char *str, int len)
{
  int slen = strlen(str);
  for (int i=0; i<len; ++i)
    Serial.print(i<slen ? str[i] : ' ');
  smartDelay(0);
}
```

Comment: Sodaq is a brand name. The company makes a variety of different Arduino compatible boards. You need to specify which Sodaq board you're using. Also, "it won't recognise it" is not a very helpful description of the problem. I can guess the actual error message from the title but you would be more likely to get a good answer if you add the actual error message to your questions rather than being so vague.

Answer (score 0):

Sodaq wrote their own softwareserial library. If you install that library, it should resolve your issues:

You can find it [here](https://github.com/SodaqMoja/Sodaq_SoftSerial).

But it doesn't work. I tried it.

But u can use this.

Hardware Serials

The SODAQ ONE has 3 hardware serials:
SerialUSB – This is for when you are debugging over the USB Cable.
Serial – Serial is attached to pin D12/A12/TX and D13/A12/RX.
Serial1 – Is connected to the RN2483 LoRaWAN Module.

Serial is connected to pin 12 and 13
SerialUSB is for debugging over the usb cable

Instead of SoftwareSerial ss(RXPin, TXPin); you could add:

`#define ss Serial`

All your code with Serial must be SerialUSB

And then something else. Are u still using a gps module or is this a gns? If so you can try neogps. Here is an example for the sodaq explorer.

https://github.com/Kaasfabriek/Junior_Internet_of_Things_2018/blob/master/test_NMEAloc/test_NMEAloc.ino

For the sodaq explorer u might need a hack if u will use neogps like this.
https://github.com/Kaasfabriek/Junior_Internet_of_Things_2018/tree/master/hack

Neogps can be found here. I see u are using tinygps, if u have a gps that talks gps dialect that will work. If u have a gns it won't.

https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoGPS

Comment: Can give some guidance on *how* to install the library?